# How can I debug WSL Bash script

Tags: bash, debugging, visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have a bash script that I run in WSL that also calls other scripts and it is quite complex for me to debug by hand, so I decided to try to debug it in VS code. The problem is that it seems that it doesn't have access to full WSL functionality.

Here is how it is set up:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "bashdb",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Bash-Debug (simplest configuration)",
            "program": "E:/Documents/Code/AndroidBuild/AndroidBuild.sh"
        }
    ]
}
```

And when I run it seems that it only has access to the simplest bash commands and can't access components installed on WSL:

```
PS E:\Documents\Code> cd '.'; & 'wsl.exe' 'bash' '-c' 'cd "/mnt/e/Documents/Code"; while [[ ! -p "/tmp/vscode-bash-debug-fifo-12281" ]]; do sleep 0.25; done; "bash" "/mnt/c/Users/Jzuken/.vscode/extensions/rogalmic.bash-debug-0.3.3/bashdb_dir/bashdb" --quiet --tty "/tmp/vscode-bash-debug-fifo-12281" --tty_in "/tmp/vscode-bash-debug-fifo-12281_in" --library "/mnt/c/Users/Jzuken/.vscode/extensions/rogalmic.bash-debug-0.3.3/bashdb_dir" -- "/mnt/e/Documents/Code/AndroidBuild/AndroidBuild.sh" '
Hello World
/mnt/e/Documents/Code/AndroidBuild/AndroidBuild.sh: line 2: $'screenfetch\r': command not found
```

AndroidBuild.sh:

```
echo "Hello World"
screenfetch
```

As you see, echo works alright, but screenfetch doesn't work, even though it works if I run it inside WSL.

How can I set it up so I can debug bash scripts in native WSL environment using VS code? I also have ssh server running on my WSL that I can connect to, if that can help.

Answer (score 0):

In short you can install bashdb as a command-line debugger in WSL, either from source code or as a package. For example https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/bashdb